# Hooks to always be run efter request - also on error

Tags: mechanize, mechanize-ruby

I know that mechanize has `post_connect_hooks` that will be run after the page is retrieved. However if an exception happens e.g. if you request an unknown URL like `"http://dsjkhbgdfb.comsfg"` then it runs `pre_connect_hooks` but not `post_connect_hooks`. Is there any way to ensure `post_connect_hooks` (or something similar) to always be run?

```
agent = Mechanize.new

agent.pre_connect_hooks << lambda do |request_agent, request|
  puts "increment a counter"
end

agent.post_connect_hooks << lambda do |request_agent, uri, response, response_body|
  puts "decrement a counter"
end

agent.get("http://dsjkhbgdfb.comsfg")
#=> increment a counter
#=> SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

As you can see, the "decrement a counter" is not run, because an error occurs before.

Answer (score 0):

try this as it might just force it and ignore the error

```
try:
agent.get("http://dsjkhbgdfb.comsfg")
except socket.error:
pass # Basically, ignore the error
```